# how to make picture library in site definition?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio

If anyone knows
I want to know how to make picture library in site definition?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1. Add a new feature (Feature_1) & add a receiver code to create a library (if already not present) of type picture library (you will be giving the list type here)

> OR

1. Add a list instance based on the picture library template ID (you can find the template ID of all OOB lists in google search). Wrap this in a feature (Feature_2)

Now, you can use either of the above feature's reference in your Onet.xml under required SCOPE.

Comment: I want to make it from ListDefinition & ListInstance as we used for making custom list & document library.